# Using ionic Tabs directive inside a modal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic modal window which serves as setting's menu
plan is to use the modal with a small header and inside the content use the ion-tabs directive in a simple manner that each click shows and hide's a div

I've read the docs saying that they have a bug related to using the tabs inside a ion-content, so im aware of it.

how then can i achieve this funcionallity, if i remove the ion-content than the tabs directive is being pushed down instead of showing on top of the screen, here is the markup for the modal:

```
  <ion-modal-view>

<ion-header-bar style="background-color: #40863E">
     <h1 class="title" style="color:white;">My Account</h1>
     <div class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()"><span class="icon ion-close"></span></div>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>

         <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

              <ion-tab title="Message" icon-on=" ion-android-chat" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <!-- Tab 1 content -->
              </ion-tab>

              <ion-tab title="Payment History" icon-on="ion-social-usd" icon-off="ion-ios7-clock-outline" on-select="showPayments()">
              </ion-tab>

              <ion-tab title="Edit" icon-on="ion-android-settings" icon-off="ion-ios7-gear-outline">
                <!-- Tab 3 content -->  
              </ion-tab>

               <ion-tab title="Sign Out" icon-on="ion-log-out" icon-off="ion-ios7-gear-outline">
                <!-- Tab 3 content -->
              </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>

<div id="payments" class="row" style="margin-top:43px;height:51px;">
some payments content
</div>

</ion-content>


  </ion-modal-view>
```

*UPDATE
adding a picture to describe the problem

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to use ion-pane instead of ion-content.

Comment: Saves a ton of hassle

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<ion-content>` tag and then you can use CSS to push the top of the tabs down. ionContent is good about knowing when a header is used, but it does have some issues when ionTabs are inside. Something like the following, but you might need to use a more specific CSS selector.

```
.tabs { margin-top: 44px; }
```

Comment: i think i tried something like this and the contents of the div with id payments were shown above, but ill try it in the evning to be sure and let you know. thanks!!

Comment: If you can give the full code, I could better help make sure the CSS styles the tabs correctly.

Comment: hi jeremy , i verified again with the css property you suggested but it didnt work. i uploaded an image to describe the problem. there isnt any custom css im using at the moment ,and i havent implemented the controller so no js, the html code i have is the entire html file

Comment: @JeremyWilken, did you update the codepen example of this?  I've been trying to do the same thing.